# Programmatically expanding Tree in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to expand the first element of a tree (GUI) in google apps script? I can't see any methods for that in the API https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [TreeItem method setState()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_treeitem#setState) to open a certain tree Item of a tree.

```
function OpenItem(e)
{
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('Item0').setState(true)
  return app;
}
```

Where the `Item0` is the treeItem.

[working example](https://sites.google.com/a/lagaroo.com.br/dev-test/home/dev-test-tree-item)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this ?

```
function treetest(){
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var app = UiApp.createApplication()
var tree1 = app.createTree()
var tree2 = app.createTree()
var tree3 = app.createTree()
tree1.add(tree2)
tree1.addItem('item on tree1').addItem('item on tree1').addItem('item on tree1')
tree2.addItem('item on tree2').addItem(tree3).addItem('item on tree2').addItem('item on tree2')
tree3.addItem('item on tree3').addItem('item on tree3')
app.add(tree1)
ss.show(app)
}
```

[image]

tree2 is added to the root of tree1 and tree3 is added in the 2cond branch of tree2

Comment: Hi Serge, thanks. I think my question may have been slightly ambiguous. I already have the tree working fine. What I want to do is programmatically expand the first branch of the tree to show what is underneath it, as opposed to users having to click to open the first branch of the tree.